# connect C# to PgBouncer

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql, pgbouncer

I am using C# and PostgreSQL. I have connected to PostgreSQL using Npgsql. Everthing is working fine. Now I want to use connection pooling with the help of PgBouncer tool.Database information has been set to PgBouncer. Because now PgBouncer will take care of connection to PostgreSQL database( If I am wrong, please correct me).

But the problem is that , I could not find the way to connect PgBouncer in C#.If anyone has done the same , please tell me.

Also is it good to use connection pooling in PostgreSQL instead of PgBouncer? if yes then please tell me how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: https://pgbouncer.github.io/faq.html#how-to-connect-to-pgbouncer

Comment: Nick I don't know how to use NpgSql Connection string if we are using PgBouncer.

Comment: Just enter the host/port of your PgBouncer server instead of the host/port of your database server.

Comment: My connection string is <add key="PgSQLConnectionString" value="server=127.0.0.1;Port=6432;UserID=postgres;Password=teamWork;database=TestDB;" /> but it give me error "pgbouncer cannot connect to server (age=0)" .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using pgbouncer with Npgsql simply means making Npgsql connect to pgbouncer instead of PostgreSQL directly - all you need to do is provider the host and port for pgbouncer.

Note that Npgsql comes with an efficient, built-in connection pool which in general should be preferred - make sure you have a good reason for using pgbouncer instead of the internal pooling. Npgsql pooling is on by default, if you want to use pgbouncer you should probably disable Npgsql pooling by passing `Pooling=false` in your connection string.

> Also is it good to use connection pooling in PostgreSQL instead of PgBouncer?

That doesn't really make any sense - PostgreSQL (your database server) doesn't provide any pooling on its own.

Comment: <add key="PgSQLConnectionString" value="server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;UserID=postgres;Password=teamWork;database=TestDB;Pooling=true; Maximum Pool Size=100;" />  This connection string does not work. As you said that Npgsql comes with an efficient build in connection pool, Can I control min and max connection pool ? This is really what I need. http://www.npgsql.org/doc/index.html does not give me any information.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.npgsql.org/doc/connection-string-parameters.html#pooling - of course you can control min and max. Regarding pgbouncer, are you sure its running at localhost port 5432? You seem to be connecting directly to your PostgreSQL (pgbouncer typically runs on a different port).

Comment: [1] <add key="PgSQLConnectionString" value="server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;UserID=postgres;Password=teamWork;Pooling=true;MinPoolSize=1;MaxPoolSize=100;Timeout=60;SslMode=Disable;database=TestDB;" />   This works fine for me. I need to test more.Thanks for your suggestion.  [2] PgBouncer is running on port 6432. I am connecting to PgBouncer but it give me error "pgbouncer cannot connect to server (age=0)"

Comment: Great. Note that you don't need to specify Pooling=true, MinPoolSize=1, MaxPoolSize=100 (or SslMode=Disable) - these are all the defaults. For your PgBouncer issues, you probably have a PgBouncer-side config issue.