# Postgresql - prepared statements vs connection pooling - is it a tradeoff?

Tags: postgresql, prepared-statement, connection-pooling, npgsql, pgbouncer

It's my understanding that you can use prepared statements or connection pooling (with tools like pgPool/pgBouncer) with Postgresql, but can benefit from only one at the same time ([at least with Npgsql driver for .NET](http://www.roji.org/prepared-statements-in-npgsql-3-2), plus [library author suggests turning off clients-side connection pooling when using PgBouncer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44754319/connect-c-sharp-to-pgbouncer)). Am I right? 
 
If so - is this true for other runtimes and languages, like Java, Python, Go? Or is it a implementation-specific issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a complex question, but here are some answers.

As @laurenz-albe writes, you can use pgbouncer and prepared statements but need to use session pooling. This allows you to use prepared statements for the duration of your connection (i.e. as long as your NpgsqlConnection instance is open). However, if you're in a short-lived connection scenario (e.g. web app which opens and closes a connection for each HTTP request), you're out of luck. In this sense, one could say that pooling and prepared statements aren't compatible.

However, if you use Npgsql's internal pooling mechanism (on by default) instead of pgbouncer, then your prepared statements are automatically persisted across connection open/close. In other words, when you call `NpgsqlCommand.Prepare()`, if the physical connection happened to have already prepared the SQL, then the prepared statement is reused. This is done specifically to unlock the speed advantages of prepared statements for short-lived connection scenarios. This is a pretty unique behavior of Npgsql, [see the docs for more info](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/prepare.html#persistency).

This is one of the advantages of an in-process connection pool, as opposed to an out-of-process pool such as pgbouncer - Npgsql retains information on the physical connection as it is passed around, in this case a table of which statements are prepared (name and SQL).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a generic question, so I'll give a generic answer. What aspect is applicable to a specific connection pool implementation will probably vary.

There are several modes of connection pooling:

- A thread retains a connection for the duration of a session (session pooling):
  In that case, persistent state like prepared statements can be held for the duration of the session, but you should clean the state when the session is returned to the pool.
- A thread retains a connection for the duration of a database transaction (transaction pooling):
  In that case, you'd have to clean the state after each transaction, so prepared statements don't make much sense.
- A thread retains a connectoin for the duration of a statement (statement poling):
  This is only useful in very limited cases where you don't need transactions spanning more than a single statement. Obviously, no state like prepared statements can be shared.

It depends what kind of connection pool you use. Basically, the longer a thread retains a connection, the more sense it makes to use prepared statements.

Of course, if you know what you are doing, you can also create a prepared statement right after the database connection is established and never deallocate it. This will only work if all threads need the same prepared statements. It is easy to screw up with a setup like that.

Comment: so the answer to my first question is "it depends"?

Comment: I'd say so, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Since PgBouncer 1.21.0 it now supports protocol level named prepared statements in transaction pooling mode. So it's not a tradeoff anymore and you can use both at the same time. You can turn this support on by setting `max_prepared_statements` to a non-zero value in PgBouncer its config file. For details check the docs: https://www.pgbouncer.org/config.html#max_prepared_statements